# Coffeescript live toggle

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How do I turn this into a live jquery toggle (coffeescript)?

```
$('.link').toggle(
  -> $(this).text('less'); $('.entry').css('height', 'auto'),
  -> $(this).text('more'); $('.entry').css('height', '300px')
)
```

I have tried wrapping this in a live function, but then it only triggers the first event, and will not toggle back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using .on, I'm assuming .link is inserted into the DOM dynamically, correct?

```
var hasToggle = false

$('body').on('click', '.link', (e) ->
  unless hasToggle
    $(@).toggle(
      -> 
        $(@).text('less')
        $('.entry').css('height', 'auto')
      ->
        $(@).text('more')
        $('.entry').css('height', '300px')
    )
  hasToggle = true
)
```

I think the reason it wasn't working is because everytime you click on .link with .on or .live its re-initializing a new .toggle event, so you're always going to call the first function in .toggle. If you set the event once for .toggle the first time a user clicks on it that may solve your problem.

Comment: That works great, thanks! The only problem now is that I have to click the .link twice the first time for the toggle to be triggered. The .link is already on the page, then the content where .link is is reloaded using ajax.

Comment: I would hate to suggest this, but it would solve the clicking twice problem, you could call $(@).click() right after you setup your .toggle. I don't think its a very clean solution but it would work.